# Black dots when plotting countourf?

Tags: python, matplotlib, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

I'm plotting contours to visually represent my neural network classification with a given set of data. I've noticed these black dots appear as the model is training through all its epochs. What do they represent?

Code is as follows (skipped explaining how neural network was constructed):

```py
# Plotting Function
def plot_model(sess, model, xy, labels, feature_lambda, title=''):
  from pandas import DataFrame
  xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1.2,1.2,400), np.linspace(-1.2,1.2,400))
  prediction = sess.run(model, feed_dict={X: np.array([feature_lambda(xxval, yyval) for xxval, yyval in zip(xx.flatten(), yy.flatten())])})
  Z = prediction.reshape(xx.shape)
  df = DataFrame(dict(x=xy[:,0], y=xy[:,1], label=labels.flatten()))
  markers = {0:'bs', 1:'r^'}
  _, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
  cs = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, 20, cmap='coolwarm', alpha=.9)
  ax.clabel(cs, colors='gray')
  cs = ax.contour(xx, yy, Z, cmap='gray', levels=[0, 0.5, 1.0], linestyles='--', linewidths=2)
  ax.clabel(cs, colors='k')
  predictions = sess.run(model, feed_dict={X: xy})
  for k, xy0 in df[['x', 'y']].iterrows():
      x0, y0 = xy0.values
      plt.plot(x0, y0, markers[labels[k][0]], mec='k')
  ax.set_xlim([-1.1, 1.1])
  ax.set_ylim([-1.1, 1.1])
  plt.grid(linestyle='--', alpha=0.5)
  plt.title(title)
  plt.show()

# Generate data
xy, labels = make_blobs(n_samples=200, center_box=(-1, 1), centers=6, cluster_std=0.1, random_state=20)
labels = labels % 2
labels = labels.reshape(-1, 1)
ftr_fn = lambda x, y: [x, y]
features = np.array([ftr_fn(xval, yval) for xval, yval in xy])

# Stochastic Method
batch_size = 25
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for epoch in range(MaxEpoch):
  if epoch % 5 == 0:
    curr_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X: features, y: labels})
    plot_model(sess, yhat, xy, labels, ftr_fn, 'Epoch {} \n (loss={:.3f})'.format(epoch, curr_loss))
  for X_batch, y_batch in generate_batches(batch_size, features_shuffled, labels_shuffled):
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
loss_final = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X: features, y: labels})
plot_model(sess, yhat, xy, labels, ftr_fn, 'Epoch 25 \n (loss={:.3f})'.format(loss_final))
```

[Epoch 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAYFO.png)

[Epoch 10 - Bottom Right Corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h7xH.png)

[Epoch 25 - Bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we2Ff.png)

Comment: It's only a picture. Elaborate more how this plot is created. Question needs more clarity and debugging information.

Comment: whoops, forgot to add in the code

Comment: Those are your zero contour, aren’t they?